# Given a date, how can I generate a dropdown list containing subsequent dates?

Tags: php, html

I have created a form for a user to request a lesson. Each individual record will be added to the table on form submit, however I don't know how I can automatically generate options in a select box for dates. Ideally, I'd like the select box to generate dates for 10 days, in 2 days from the current date.

For instance, today is 23rd, the first option available would be dated 2013-05-25. Nine additional options would be added for the following nine days.

```
<select name="day1">
    <option value="2013-05-25">Sat, 25th May 2013</option>
    <option value="2013-05-26">Sun, 26th May 2013</option>
</select>
```

I was wondering how I could quickly generate these into options on a select box?

Comment: Like you have done! Do you mean iterate through dates and generate it automatically?

Comment: Yes, generate them automatically and input them as options, sorry.

Comment: Use the dateperiod class from PHP base. http://php.net/manual/en/class.dateperiod.php This allows you to iterate through the exact increments you want and look up subsequent dates.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this should do the trick (not tested):

```
// Create the dates array
$dates = array();

// Loop through 9 times (9 days)
for($i=0;$i<9;$i++){
    // Set the timestamp
    // This starts in 2 days
    $timestamp = strtotime('+ '.(2+$i).' days');
    // Set the date value
    $date = date('Y-m-d',$timestamp);
    // Set the formatted date value
    $date_formatted = date('D, js F Y',$timestamp);
    // Place the date into the $dates array
    $dates[$date] = $date_formatted;
}
```

And then loop through the `$dates` array like so:

```
echo "<select name=\"day1\">";

foreach($dates as $key=>$value){
   echo "<option value=\"$key\">$value</option>";
}

echo "</select>";
```

Furthermore, if you wanted to create several of these select boxes then place them within a for loop like so:

```
// This will create 5 select boxes
for($i=0;$i<5;$i++){

    echo "<select name=\"day$i\">";

    foreach($dates as $key=>$value){
       echo "<option value=\"$key\">$value</option>";
    }

    echo "</select>";

}
```

In order to understand what is going on above, you need to understand how three things work:

1. `for` and `foreach` loops. See [here](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.for.php) and [here](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php)
2. The `strtotime()` function, see documentation [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php)
3. And finally, the `date()` function, see documentation [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php)

Comment: Thank you :) The semi-colon on the loop line of 9 days throws a parse error, once removed it bizarrely adds 15 on the end of the day number in the option i.e `Mon, 2715 May 2013`

Comment: Thanks for the update Ben. I know how `foreach` works (I used `for` before but briefly), however I never worked with `strtotime()` before, thank you for those links.

Comment: @HighFlyerPL185 I have also updated to fix semicolons, there may be other errors. How is it going?

Comment: @HighFlyerPL185 Just debug it, error should be pretty simple to find :-)

Comment: `$date_formatted = date('D, js /* s was counting seconds 0-60, noticed that while refreshing the page, changed this to j */ F Y',$timestamp);` And it works :) Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

for the next 10 days starting in two days:

```
echo "<select name='date'>";
for($i=3;$i<=12;$i++){
   echo "<option>".date("Y-m-d",strtotime("+$i days"))."</option>";        
}
echo "</select>";
```